# Thin server : `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)

Tags: port, thin

My thin webserver fails to start with an error message.
I can hardly find any information or leads on how to fix this, anyone an idea? thx

> > Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
> >     Maximum connections set to 1024
> >     Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
> >     /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:526:in`start_server'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/tcp_server.rb:16:in `connect'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:55:in`block in start'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in`run_machine'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in`start'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in`run'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in`start'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in`load'
> >         from /srv/gamers/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rackup:19:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today.  I found this and it may help point you in the right direction.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923990/why-do-i-get-connection-refused-after-1024-connections

I was doing some testing, had lunch, came back and fired up the server and got the error too.  I did a quick work around by using port 3002 instead of 3001 that I was just on.  I will try to do this fix later. Did you find a solution?

Comment: havent found a solution yet its specific to using redis on a rails project wich uses the thin server for part of a web interface. But its a thin issue and i decided to threat it as such

Answer (score 0):

Are you running another process on port 3000 (aka maybe running another rails project, possibly in another terminal tab)? This error usually means, as it states, that it's already in use. Honestly, it's happened to me a few times when I forgot to quit another rails app and I attempt to start up another.